# Salesforce x Docusign: could not be activated - [USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED] One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit, e-signature

I'm using Esignature Salesforce with Docusign, and I when I tried to add a new user to the Docusign by the Salesforce, I'm receiving the follow error:

could not be activated - [USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED] One or both of Username and Password are invalid.
This error occurs to some users only.
I saw in the Slaesforce and Docusign log and there is no error appearing on the log.
Is someone know what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this typically means the Salesforce username/email combination already exists as an active user on the account server they're trying to add them to. They can either a) have those other users on the other accounts closed, or b) In versions 7.2.1+ resolve it with this workaround:
User Authentication Failed Workaround

1. Add the user directly in DocuSign > Admin > Users
2. Have the user complete the activation steps.
3. Go to the Object Manager
4. Go to Users
5. Go to Page Layouts and edit the User Details Page Layout
6. Add the DocuSign Username Field (might be labeled DSProSFUsername), to the layout
7. Login directly to DocuSign
8. Go to Admin
9. Go to Users
10. Click on the affected User and copy their API Username
11. Go back to Salesforce and Edit the User Record
12. Paste in the API Username into that DocuSign Username field.
13. Add the DocuSign User or DocuSign Administrator Permission Set Assignment Manually
14. Go to the Apex Troubleshooting page here: https://support.docusign.com/articles/How-do-I-troubleshoot-issues-with-DocuSign-for-Salesforce-configurations-settings
15. Run a Force User Sync.

Comment: Hi Inbar Gazit,

Thank you your help, you saved my life.
I did all the steps that you mentioned and now it seens that all is working fine.
Thanks a lot.